# React-native & Async Storage : App crashes every 5-10 min and all data lost on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I made my first app with React-native / Redux / Async Storage. Everthing works fine on my Android 10.0 Emulator API 29 but in a real device (Samsung S9 or Galaxy Tab), the app crashes every 5-10 min in first situation (see below) or sometimes in second situation. In any case, all data is lost after.

I know that I won't be clear and precise in my explanations because I can't find where the problem is. So do not hesitate to ask me some additionals informations. I can't put all my code here but if needed, I can share some part of it or a github.

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.14",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-camera-hooks": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.29.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-print": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.0",
    "react-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
```

**First situation**

I use react-native-camera to take pictures and then I save them to the Redux Store in base64 (is that a good idea?). When I use this function, I have the impression that the app crashes faster.

So when I take picutres, the application is consuming more and more memory RAM. I begin at 90MB and after few minutes 200MB and then 400MB... If I stop it before 400MB, the application starts again at 90MB and everthing is ok. If not, the application crashes (or not) but all data is lost.

The second thing I noticed is that the pictures seem to stay on the cache memory. Maybe it is a configuration that I need to put.

**Second situation**

I disable the save of the pictures and it seems that the application do not crash after 5-10 min. I can use it for 30 min and all worked fine. I just noticed a crash one time and all data is lost again (one too many).

About the memory, it seems that the application doesn't consume as much as the situation where we save the pictures. It begins at 90MB then 170MB to 220MB but never more.

**So now, my question is :**

How can i diagnose this type of problem ? All works fine on the emulator (no errors in console, the app never crashes).

Could this be a known issue with Async Storage / Redux / Or the organization of my data? (I searched about this type of problem but the majority of data lost is after an update)

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Sounds like you're likely running out of memory.  200 MB is large for an Android app, many devices you're at around the cap there.  400MB is enormous.  Of course figuring out where your problem is is going to be hard-  its hard in a native app, but in a react app where a heap dump is just going to give a bunch of C objects in the interpreter its impossible using native tools.  I'd look for a RN heap dump tool of some sort that can specify what the js objects are that are staying around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the app with Android Studio Profiler (second situation) . It consumes appr. 100-120MB of RAM but when I use "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0" it adds 50-60MB on it and it is never emptied except when I close the app. Is there a way to clear this in memory?